# How to check that bitfields span all the bits

Tags: c++

I have a structure which looks like this:

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct bits {
    uint8_t u_     : 1;
    uint8_t k_     : 1;
    uint8_t c_     : 1;

    uint8_t x_     : 1;
    uint8_t b_     : 1;

    uint8_t ns_    : 1;
    uint8_t ms_    : 1;
    uint8_t as_    : 1;
    uint8_t /*padding1*/ : 0;

    uint8_t st_    : 3;
    uint8_t su_    : 1;
    uint8_t ig_    : 1;

    uint8_t h_     : 1;
    uint8_t in_    : 1;

    uint8_t pad2_  : 1;

    bits_t(uint8_t u, uint8_t k, uint8_t c, uint8_t x, uint8_t b,
           uint8_t n, uint8_t m, uint8_t a, uint8_t s, uint8_t i,
           bool h, bool in)
       : u_    { u }
       , k_    { k }
       , c_    { c }
       , x_    { x }
       , b_    { b }
       , ns_   { n }
       , ms_   { m }
       , as_   { a }
       , st_   { 0 }
       , su_   { s }
       , ig_   { i }
       , h_    { h }
       , in_   { in }
       , pad2_ { 0 } // carefully initialize all bits
    {}
};
```

These structs have an `operator==` using `memcmp`, so it's important that all bits are set to a known value in the constructor.

Recently, I realized that `h_` and `in_` are doing the same thing except in reverse, i.e. `assert(h_ == !in_)` always holds true. I'm about to remove `h_` and I'd like some compile-time check that would warn me that `pad2_` needs to be extended from `: 1` to `: 2`.

Is this possible? I couldn't think of anything (`sizeof(bits)` would be the same with or without the `h_` field).

Comment: The standard is quite loose regarding padding between members. If you read the documentation for [bit fields](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) you'll notice that members *may* be packed bitwise, but it's not guaranteed. There is no trait that detects padding between members.

Comment: Comparing bit fields with `memcmp` is not portable. Why not just use `uint32_t` with bitwise ops?

Comment: _"The following properties of bit fields are implementation-defined: __(*) Everything about the actual allocation details of bit fields within the class object__"_ source: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field  You will need to consult your implementation documentation.

Comment: NB. the C++ header to include is `<cstdint>`

Comment: @RustyX I have a separate `union { uint32_t all_bits_; bits bits_ }` when I want to manipulate all the bits in one go. `memcmp` of uint32_t is surely portable.

Comment: @Bulletmagnet that union will give you UB

Comment: You can use an array of uint8_t with an enum if you need to name the fields. I wouldn't count on memory padding to stay the same for all platforms

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux bitset will not work for fields which are not `: 1` (e.g. `st_`)

Answer (score 1):

There is as such no way to query of the offsets of bitfield. So it would be difficult to create any constraints on the bitfields. Although the following pre processing trick can help you achieve what you need.

What you essentially need to do is create your struct fields using macros.

Your normal struct with 2 bit fields can be made as follows

```
#define STRUCT_NAME my_bitfield
#define FIELD_LIST \
     FIELD(a,3) \
     FIELD(b,5) 

#define FIELD(x,y) int x:y;
struct STRUCT_NAME {
     FIELD_LIST 
};
```

Everything fine till now. Now what we will do is create an auxiliary struxt which has parallel elements but each being n bytes as

```
#undef FIELD
#define FIELD(x,y) char x[y];
struct aux_##STRUCT_NAME {
    FIELD_LIST
};
```

Cool. Now we have an advantage. We can take `sizeof` of this aux struct and check if it is multiple of 8

```
static_assert(sizeof(struct aux_##STRUCT_NAME) % 8 == 0);
```

This now automatically checks if your bitfield struct has enough bit padding.

Finally to resuse this code you can add the actually generation code inside a .h file and in your main code, just redefine `FIELD_LIST` and `STRUCT_NAME` and include the header.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best option is disregard padding, and bluntly set the entire memory layout to zero **before** assigning any values.

Something like this:

```
bits_t::bits_t(uint8_t u, uint8_t k, uint8_t c, uint8_t x, uint8_t b,
        uint8_t n, uint8_t m, uint8_t a, uint8_t s, uint8_t i, bool h, bool in) {

  //Sanity check that memset(this) is valid
  static_assert(std::is_pod<bits_t>::value, "");
  memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));

   u_  = u;
   ...
}
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the padding memory would remain zero.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I read OP's concern is about uninitialized memory when the bitfield leaves unasigned bits after refactoring. This would handle it.

Comment: @user2079303 are you implying that `sizeof()` doesn't include the padding?

Comment: No, I'm implying that setting the padding to zero has no useful effect.

Comment: @user2079303 The point is not to have padding memory. Just because a field is called `pad2` it's still a valuable member of the struct :)

Comment: @Bulletmagnet To clarify my previous comments: by padding I mean bits that are not part of any bit field, not the bit field named `pad`.

Comment: @user2079303 If you use `memcmp` then if the padding is not the same it will make a difference.

Comment: @user2079303 I see what you mean, you are implying that assigning a bitfield could randomly stomp memory if the next bits happen to be padding memory. That's just not correct.

Comment: @Frank I see. If I'm incorrect, then this will work. Could you point out the rule that guarantees this?

Comment: @user2079303 I'm not sure about the exact rule, but a quick test with GCC indicates it's operating this way: https://godbolt.org/g/zV7guV, I'll try and find the reference for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be sure of a particular size, etc. for efficnency, compatibility, etc., you could use `static_assert`, e.g. `static_assert(sizeof(bits) == 2, "Expected 16 bits")` and could potentially do likewise for each actual field.

More generally however for structs you will memcmp, etc. just make sure you use `sizeof` everywhere with such functions. e.g. you could do.

```
struct bits
{
    ... fields ....

    bits()
    {
        memset(this, 0, sizeof(*this));
    }
    bits(bool flag_a)
      : bits()
    {
        // doesnt matter if some were missed, other constructor called memset
        _flag_a = flag_a;
    }
    bits(const bits &cp)
    {
        // important, default copy constructor, operator, etc. may leave padding as anything!
        memcpy(this, &cp, sizeof(*this));
    }
};
bool operator == (bits &lhs, bits &rhs)
{
    return memcmp(&lhs, &rhs, sizeof(bits)) == 0;
}
bool operator != (bits &lhs, bits &rhs)
{
    return memcmp(&lhs, &rhs, sizeof(bits)) != 0;
}
```

Comment: ah yes of course, also double initialisation doesnt make sense :) so much for shortening example code

Answer (score 0):

The only *portable* way to control exactly the layout and padding of your type, is to not use bitfields in the first place.

Eg, have some type wrapping an enum and `std::bitset` instead. This means splitting your `st_` member into three bits, or having a special accessor for that one field. Everything else is straightforward though, and the bit count is available to `static_assert` at compile time.

Note that you still can't use `memcmp` for this, but you get `std::bitset::operator ==` for free.